# Using TailwindCss in Storybook 6 with Angular

Tags: angular, tailwind-css, storybook

I am building a component library with Angular (11.2.8) and I try to add TailwindCss and Storybook 6.

I have found different configuration but none of them work. My components have no style when I run storybook.

Here is my configuration :

`.storybook/main.js`

```js
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../projects/storybook/**/*.stories.ts'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-actions',
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-knobs',
    '@storybook/addon-viewport',
    '@storybook/addon-docs',
    '@storybook/addon-a11y',
    '@storybook/addon-storysource'
  ],
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {

    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\,css&/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'postcss-loader',
          options: {
            ident: 'postcss',
            plugins: [
              require('tailwindcss'),
              require('autoprefixer')
            ]
          }
        },
      ],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
    });

    return config;
  }
};
```

`.storybook/preview.js`

```js
import '../src/styles.scss';
import { setCompodocJson } from '@storybook/addon-docs/angular';
import docJson from '../documentation/documentation.json';
setCompodocJson(docJson);
```

`src/styles.scss`

```css
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:prod": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "docs:json": "compodoc -d documentation -p projects/test/tsconfig.lib.json -e json ",
    "storybook": "npm run docs:json && start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "npm run docs:json && build-storybook -o dist/storybook"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.7",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.7",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.7",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.7",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.3.2",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.4.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/jest": "^11.1.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.7",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.7",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.11",
    "@storybook/addon-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.2.1",
    "@storybook/addon-docs": "^6.2.1",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^6.2.1",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.2.1",
    "@storybook/addon-storysource": "^6.2.1",
    "@storybook/addon-viewport": "^6.2.1",
    "@storybook/addons": "^6.2.1",
    "@storybook/angular": "^6.2.1",
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.1.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.22",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "ng-packagr": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss": "^7.0.35",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.1.0",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.4",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
  }
}
```

`projects/test/storybook/src/stories/button.stories`

```js
import { boolean, text, select } from '@storybook/addon-knobs';
import { moduleMetadata } from '@storybook/angular';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {ButtonComponent, ButtonModule} from 'test';

const title = 'Button';
export default {
  title,
  component: ButtonComponent,
  decorators: [
    moduleMetadata({
      imports: [ButtonModule, CommonModule]
    })
  ]
};

const template = `
    <test-button
    [size]="size"
    [outline]="outline"
    [block]="block"
    [loading]="loading"
    [disabled]="disabled"
    (click)="clicked">
    {{content}}
    </test-button>
`;

const defaultProps = () => {
  return {
    content: text('content', 'text'),
    loading: boolean('loading', false),
    type: select('type', {
      text: 'text',
      submit: 'submit'
    }, 'text'),
    size: select('size', {
      sm: 'sm',
      lg: 'lg',
      xl: 'xl'
    }, null),
    outline: boolean('outline', null),
    block: boolean('block', null),
    disabled: boolean('disabled', null)
  };
};

export const Button = () => ({
  template,
  props: defaultProps()
});
```

`projects/test/.../button.component.html`

```html
   <button class="px-4 border border-transparent shadow-sm text-sm font-medium rounded-md bg-red-400 text-primary py-2" [type]="type" [ngClass]="classes" [attr.disabled]="loading || disabled ? 'disabled' : null"
            (click)="clicked.emit($event)">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </button>`
```

`tailwind.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  prefix: '',
  purge: {
  },
  darkMode: 'class', // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: '#ecc94b',
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/forms'),require('@tailwindcss/typography')],
};
```

Tailwind styles are not applied

[image: button with no custom style]

[image: dev console]

I don't know what is missing in my configuration

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this template which comes with Angular 12, Tailwind 2.1 JIT and Storybook 6.3. This repo also got atomic folder structure just in case you are into it. It's got the latest Ivy rendering pipeline as well, improves performance.

https://github.com/newwwton/angular-tailwind-storybook

Comment: Thanks for sharing you example @jerric. It would be really great if you could talk about how you solved this issue. Have you tried your implementation in Angular library?

Comment: Need some more information about how to config story please, After running the default project, Tailwind style's not showing as properties

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue might be with the fact that storybook needs to have `css` files and not `scss`, so you need an appropriate webpack loader for your `scss` files.

I have this on my `preview.js` file and tailwind worked out of the box for me.

```
import '!style-loader!css-loader!./styles.css';
```

And my `styles.scss` contains the tailwind imports like you have:

```
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```

NB: you need to npm install `style-loader` and `css-loader` in your project

Comment: Unfortunately, the described approach, does not work for me.

Comment: Adding the style-loader & css-loader worked for me, I had to also build the tailwind css using this `npx tailwindcss -o projects/shared/.storybook/styles.css -i projects/shared/.storybook/styles.scss --config ./tailwind.config.js`